# Javascript/Jquery: Most efficient way to find index of first and last array with key-value pair in nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a nested array that looks something like this:

```
route = [{
  instruction: "Walk to the New York Train Station",
  type: "WALK"
}, {
  instruction: "Take the train to Chicago Train Station",
  type: "TRANSIT"
}, {
  instruction: "Take the metro to Randolph Street",
  type: "TRANSIT"
}, {
  instruction: "Walk to the restaurant",
  type: "WALK"
}, ];
```

I want to find the indexes of the first and the last array where `type: "WALK"` in this nested array. How could I do this using Jquery and/or JavaScript?

Comment: Hey how about finding type: "WALK" array from begining and Once you encounter that begin search from last element...Does it make little better ?? :P

Comment: What about two loops: one from first element till last one or first element with 'walk' type and the second loop from the last element till first or element with 'walk' type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Array.filter`:

```js
var route = [
  { instruction: "Walk to the New York Train Station",
    type:        "WALK"
  },
  { instruction: "Take the train to Chicago Train Station",
    type:        "TRANSIT"
  },
  { instruction: "Take the metro to Randolph Street",
    type:        "TRANSIT"
  },
  { instruction: "Walk to the restaurant",
    type:        "WALK"
  },
];
var routeFiltered = route.filter(
  function (v, i) { v.index = i; return v.type === 'WALK' }
  //                ^ add index value
);
  
document.querySelector('#result').textContent = 
  JSON.stringify(routeFiltered, null, ' ');
  

// if it's just the indexes you need - use Array.map:
document.querySelector('#result').textContent += 
  '\n\nindexes of route-elements of type \'WALK\': '+ 
  routeFiltered.map( function (v) { return v.index } );
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Array.forEach`.

```js
var route = [{
  instruction: "Walk to the New York Train Station",
  type: "WALK"
}, {
  instruction: "Take the train to Chicago Train Station",
  type: "TRANSIT"
}, {
  instruction: "Take the metro to Randolph Street",
  type: "TRANSIT"
}, {
  instruction: "Walk to the restaurant",
  type: "WALK"
}, ];

var result = [];

route.forEach(function(item){
  if(item.type === "WALK"){
    result.push(item);
  }
})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use **[UnderscoreJs](http://underscorejs.org/)**.

```js
var route = [
  { instruction: "Walk to the New York Train Station",
    type:        "WALK"
  },
  { instruction: "Take the train to Chicago Train Station",
    type:        "TRANSIT"
  },
  { instruction: "Foo Bar",
    type:        "WALK"
  },
  { instruction: "Take the metro to Randolph Street",
    type:        "TRANSIT"
  },
  { instruction: "Walk to the restaurant",
    type:        "WALK"
  },
];

var firstIndex = _.findIndex(route, { type: "WALK" });
console.log(route[firstIndex]);

var lastIndex = _.findLastIndex(route, { type: "WALK" });
console.log(route[lastIndex]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore-min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var indexes = [];
function findIndexOf(value,i) {
  if(value.type == "WALK"){
        indexes.push(i);
        return true;
    }
}
var filtered = route.filter(findIndexOf);
console.log(indexes);
```

[demo](https://jsfiddle.net/nagesh521/pgzy5tj9/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
route = [
{ instruction: "Walk to the New York Train Station",
    type:        "WALK"
},
{ instruction: "Take the train to Chicago Train Station",
    type:        "TRANSIT"
},
{ instruction: "Walk to the restaurant",
    type:        "WALK"
},
{ instruction: "Walk to the restaurant",
    type:        "WALK"
},
{ instruction: "Take the metro to Randolph Street",
    type:        "TRANSIT"
},
{ instruction: "Walk to the restaurant",
    type:        "WALK"
},
];

var indices = [];
for(var i = 0; i < route.length; i++) {
    if(route[i].type === 'WALK') {
        indices.push(i);
    }
}   
console.log("First :"+indices[0]+" Last : "+indices[indices.length-1]);
```